# vb.net delete from access database

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to simply delete data from my access database on the click of a button..
But can't get it to work.

```
Dim Cmd2 As OleDbCommand
Dim SQL2 As String
Dim objCmd2 As New OleDbCommand
Dim Con2 = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Privat\dreamware\dreamware_db.mdb")
SQL2 = "DELETE FROM dreamware_db WHERE id='21'"
Cmd2 = New OleDbCommand(SQL2, Con2)
Con2.Open()
objCmd2 = New OleDbCommand(SQL2, Con2)
objCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
Con2.Close()
```

Can someone spot the error?

Comment: Have you a table in your db called "dreamware_db"? If not, you are trying to call a Delete command on Database name. You have to call a Delete command on a Table.

Comment: Yes I have a table called dreamware_db.

Comment: Good, can you post the error (if you have an error)?

Comment: your id field is integer or string

Comment: Of course, these are errors:
"Dim objCmd2 As New OleDbCommand" because you call the NEW with parameters later. 
Then, Dim Cmd2 As OleDbCommand, because you don't use it. Try to correct in this way:
"
Dim objCmd2 As OleDbCommand
"      
and remove CMD2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write your method without errors:

```
Dim SQL As String
Dim objCmd As OleDbCommand
Dim Con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Privat\dreamware\dreamware_db.mdb")

SQL = "DELETE FROM dreamware_db WHERE id='21'"

Con.Open()
objCmd = New OleDbCommand(SQL, Con)
objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Con.Close()
```

Comment: No problem, we're here to help ;)